# Access to path \ojb\Debug\net5.0\Razor\Views\Home denied - Tried everything

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code, razor, permission-denied

I have a .net MVC project that I started getting the below error on when I run it now. Ive tried: Running as Administrator, Turn off-read only for folder/subfolders, from command line and IDE terminal, Excluding all directories in Windows Defender.

Im pretty stuck here guys. Everything I've found online I've tried but no success. If anyone has something new I didn't list to try, i'd be very grateful. Thanks

[screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3j2E.png)

Comment: Reboot machine.

Comment: I have seen similar in the situation where I have an instance of my app running, but DO NOT REALIZE that instance still exists.  The previous running instance has a lock on the folder.
Check TASKMGR for another instance or just reboot as suggested by @TawabWakil

Comment: that wasn't it. reboot, instance running - neither of those were the issue